# How to make key for other column in the same table?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm making a database in sqlite3. This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RESIDENTS(
ID          VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
Roommate_ID VARCHAR(10),
Name        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

I want to be able to pair residents with one another. By changing the Roommate_ID of one resident, that resident should change its Roommate_ID to the original resident's ID. If one resident is deleted, the the Roommate_ID for its roommate should become null. How should I do this?

Comment: You would need a trigger to do that.  What happens if three people are roommates?

Comment: Only 2 people can be roommates.

Comment: How would I implement the trigger?